# Invalid procedure call or argument when taking square root (to the power of 0.5)

Tags: vba, square-root

I'm writing a script to calculate A square root of a certain value inside a macro. The code can run without issue when I don't have "^ 0.5". However, Run-time error: '5': Invalid procedure call or argument shows up. Here is the code I executed:

```
Dim sh as worksheet
Dim wb as workbook: Set wb = workbooks("A.xlsx")
For Each sh in wb
sh.Range("J8").value = (sh.Range("J7").value / (sh.Range("J6").value - 2)) ^ 0.5
Next sh
```

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the result of `sh.Range("J7").value / (sh.Range("J6").value - 2)` negative?

Comment: can be positive or negative. I have multiple sheets so there are some negative figures. Is there any method to cope with such an issue?

Comment: What do you want the result to be if that value is negative? E.g. that value equals `-4`. What do you want J8 to be?

Comment: Good question, guess an absolute value would do the work.

Comment: Then call `Abs` on the value before square rooting perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, I will probably sum the squared difference then take the square root.

Comment: Note that the `Sqr` function also exists as an alternative to `^ 0.5`.

Comment: thanks, just curious, within the macro, will sqr function take longer time than ^ 0.5?

Comment: Doubtful but you could always test it.

Comment: noted, many thanks